# Writing a script for CotEditor to insert numbers to text

Tags: applescript

I'm trying to write an AppleScript that works within CotEditor to insert numbers inside lines of text, specifying where to add it, from what number, the increment, prefixes/suffixes and choosing to add leading zeros, but it doesn't work.

```
-- Handler to add leading zeros to a number
on addLeadingZeros(numberText, maxDigits)
    set numLength to length of numberText
    set zerosToAdd to maxDigits - numLength
    if zerosToAdd > 0 then
        set leadingZeros to ""
        repeat zerosToAdd times
            set leadingZeros to leadingZeros & "0"
        end repeat
        return leadingZeros & numberText
    else
        return numberText
    end if
end addLeadingZeros

try
    tell application "CotEditor"
        if exists front document then
            set frontDoc to front document
            set docText to contents of frontDoc
            set lineList to paragraphs of docText
            set totalLines to count of lineList
            
            -- Prompt the user to enter the start line, end line, column position, starting number, and step increment
            set startLineDialog to display dialog "Start on line:" default answer "1"
            if button returned of startLineDialog is "Cancel" then return
            set startLine to text returned of startLineDialog
            
            set endLineDialog to display dialog "End on line:" default answer totalLines as rich text
            if button returned of endLineDialog is "Cancel" then return
            set endLine to text returned of endLineDialog
            
            set columnPositionDialog to display dialog "Column position:" default answer "1"
            if button returned of columnPositionDialog is "Cancel" then return
            set columnPosition to text returned of columnPositionDialog
            
            set startingNumberDialog to display dialog "Starting number:" default answer "1"
            if button returned of startingNumberDialog is "Cancel" then return
            set startingNumber to text returned of startingNumberDialog
            
            set stepIncrementDialog to display dialog "Step increment:" default answer "1"
            if button returned of stepIncrementDialog is "Cancel" then return
            set stepIncrement to text returned of stepIncrementDialog
            
            try
                set {startLine, endLine, columnPosition, startingNumber, stepIncrement} to {startLine as integer, endLine as integer, columnPosition as integer, startingNumber as integer, stepIncrement as integer}
            on error
                display dialog "Please enter valid input values." buttons {"OK"} default button "OK"
                return
            end try
            
            -- Prompt the user for a prefix
            set prefixDialog to display dialog "Enter the prefix for line numbers:" default answer ""
            if button returned of prefixDialog is "Cancel" then return
            set prefixText to text returned of prefixDialog
            
            -- Prompt the user for a suffix
            set suffixDialog to display dialog "Enter the suffix for line numbers:" default answer ""
            if button returned of suffixDialog is "Cancel" then return
            set suffixText to text returned of suffixDialog
            
            -- Ask if the user wants leading zeros
            set leadingZerosDialog to display dialog "Do you want leading zeros for line numbers?" buttons {"Yes", "No"} default button "No"
            set leadingZeros to button returned of leadingZerosDialog
            
            set newContent to ""
            set currentLineNumber to startingNumber as integer
            
            repeat with i from 1 to totalLines
                log "Processing line: " & i -- Log message to track progress
                
                if i ≥ startLine and i ≤ endLine then
                    log "Adding line number to line: " & i
                    
                    -- Calculate the appropriate prefix based on the line number
                    set lineNumberText to currentLineNumber as rich text
                    log "Line number text before leading zeros: " & lineNumberText
                    if leadingZeros is "Yes" then
                        set lineNumberText to my addLeadingZeros(lineNumberText, 5) -- assuming a maximum of 5 digits for the line number
                        log "Line number text after leading zeros: " & lineNumberText
                    end if
                    set linePrefix to prefixText & lineNumberText & suffixText
                    log "Line prefix: " & linePrefix
                    
                    -- Insert line number at specified position
                    set lineContent to item i of lineList
                    log "Original line content: " & lineContent
                    
                    if class of lineContent is rich text and lineContent is not "" then
                        -- Insert line number at specified column position
                        set linePrefixLength to length of linePrefix
                        if columnPosition > linePrefixLength then -- Check if column position is after the prefix
                            set newLineContent to (rich text 1 thru (columnPosition - linePrefixLength) of lineContent) & linePrefix & (rich text (columnPosition - linePrefixLength + 1) thru -1 of lineContent)
                        else
                            set newLineContent to linePrefix & lineContent
                        end if
                    else
                        -- If the line is empty or not text, just insert the line number
                        set newLineContent to linePrefix
                    end if
                    log "New line content: " & newLineContent
                    
                    -- Update the line content in the list
                    set item i of lineList to newLineContent
                    set currentLineNumber to currentLineNumber + stepIncrement
                end if
            end repeat
            
            -- Reassemble the document's contents
            set newContent to ""
            repeat with i from 1 to totalLines
                set newContent to newContent & item i of lineList & return
            end repeat
            
            set contents of frontDoc to newContent
        else
            display dialog "No document is currently open."
        end if
    end tell
end try
```

Comment: And what „doesn‘t work“?

Comment: It just doesn't insert the numbers

Comment: What does the outout look like?

Comment: I have some line of text and no matter what values I put in the prompts, it just doesn't insert the numbers where are supposed to

Comment: Wondering if this needs to be so detailed, or whether you could just pipe the current text selection through `nl`...?

Comment: How? I need it to work within CotEditor on the opened file via the scripting menu

Comment: Can you break this down into smaller pieces to make it easier for others to understand (might also help to debug it)? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example has some details on that.

Answer (score 0):

Here's just numbering the currently selected lines as a partial answer:

```
#!/bin/sh
#%%%{CotEditorXInput=Selection}%%%
#%%%{CotEditorXOutput=ReplaceSelection}%%%

# number_lines.sh - take in stdin, output number-prefixed lines

nl
```

Comment: `nl` has all sorts of options, you can pad with zeroes, you can start at a particular number and increment by more than one, you can format the output, etc.  `man nl` is your friend.